# deleting room mailboxes on exchange online

Tags: office365

When I try to delete the alias for a room mailbox through Exchange Online, I can see it get deleted. However, when I choose Save and come back, the mailbox reappears. It isn't getting deleted. 
For example, room_a@xyz.com is the default SMTP server I want to use. Now, I also have room_a1@xyz.com which is shown as an alias. Here lies the problem: People who book room_a@xyz.com get an e-mail for Room A. However, people who use room_a1@xyz.com also get a booking for the same room Room A. This way, a single room gets booked for two different people. To avoid this, I wish to delete the room_a1@xyz.com mailbox.

Suggestions and solutions are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are unable to remove the email alias through the EAC I would advise you to try to remove the alias using the Powershell command below

Set-Mailbox DisplayName –EmailAddress @{remove=“room_a1@xyz.com”}

Thanks,
Steve